# How to install Ubuntu for Tablets on Lenovo Thinkpad X60/X200/X220/X230 Tablet?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-touch

How to install Ubuntu for Tablets (or Unity for Tablets?) on Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet (the [X series](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:X_Series)?) Which package from which repository to install on top of standard Ubuntu to get Ubuntu for Tablets working?

Comment: Is there a specific app you're looking for, or you just want the new unity which Ubuntu Touch is using?

Comment: @dobey, yes, I want the new Unity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 15.04, then just install the `ubuntu-touch` package.

You should then be able to select the alternate session at the login screen. Be warned though, that it is not yet ready for general replacement of unity7 though, and you will likely encounter some applications not being usable, or able to launch, and similar issues.